# ES6 - Possible to destructure from object into another object property?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So I'm trying to figure out if there's any simple ES6 syntax to do the following:

If I have an object

```
const config = { foo: null, bar: null }
```

And I want to assign the values of those properties from another object such as:

```
const source = { hello: "hello", world: "world", another: "lorem", onemore: "ipsum" }
```

I want to do something like the following but it doesn't work

```
{ hello:config.foo, world:config.bar } = source
```

I know I can do something very close like:

```
{ hello:foo, world:bar } = source
```

But this creates new variables `foo` and `bar`, whereas I want to assign to existing properties on another object.  I'm just curious if there's an ES6 shorthand for this; I don't need help doing this with traditional code, I know there are a dozen ways and I already know most of them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're just missing brackets `()` around the statement.

```js
const config = {};
const source = { hello: "hello", world: "world", another: "lorem", onemore: "ipsum" };
({hello: config.foo, world: config.bar} = source);
console.log(config);
```

Comment: Ah, I was so close! Thx.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty counterintuitive syntax IMHO @TNguyen